# Magento 2: 404 for all pages in latest magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.2, 404-page

I have setup the latest Magento 2.4.2 in the local system. Now it's showing me 404 to all pages if I access the URL without `index.php`

admin URL also not working with & without index.php

I don't want to move index.php from pub to root so let me know if any other way to solve this issue.

any idea, please share.

Comment: plz run `SELECT value FROM core_config_data WHERE path="web/seo/use_rewrites"` query and should return `1`. if not change it form 0 to 1.

Comment: Pawan, It's already return 1.

Comment: then you need to check .htaccess in present at root and pub folder